# How do I get the euler rotation of a bone in pose mode?

Tags: scripting, armature, add-on, bones, pose-mode

I'm coding a live feed of the bones rotation from a IK armature, but it keeps priting 0 for all values.
This is the code:

```
def execute(self, context):
        armature = context.scene.objects["Armature"]
        bones = (
            armature.pose.bones["Segment1"], 
            armature.pose.bones["Segment2"], 
            armature.pose.bones["Segment3"])

        def to_run():
            for i in range(100):
                print(i)    
                for obj in bones:
                    loc, rot, sca = obj.matrix_basis.decompose()
            
                    print(obj.name, rot)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                
        new_thread = threading.Thread()
        new_thread.run = to_run
        new_thread.start()
```

Here I get the bones i want the info from, then cycle them in a loop to get the rotation, and it runs on a thread for the live feed.
I was able to do it with an object on object mode, so i know the problem isn't the thread or loop.

This is the output i get:

```
0
Segment1 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
Segment2 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
Segment3 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
1
Segment1 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
Segment2 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
Segment3 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
2
Segment1 <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>
Segment2 .... and so on
```

This is the armature. The bones I want the info from are the 3 angled, excluding the last(IK).
[image: This is my armature]

Answer (score 0):

obj.matrix_basis gets the transform data before constraints are applied, and IK is a constraint. You want obj.matrix instead, and you can use rot.to_euler() to convert it to euler. For reference: https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/mathutils.html?#mathutils.Quaternion.to_euler

Comment: Ok, that worked perfectly. Thank you Very much.